# extend NopCommerce 3.6 model

Tags: entity-framework-6, nopcommerce

i need to import a new table in Nop database, and i need to create the data access layer like others tables.
The table has a primary key column which name is SignatureId and my client don't want to change this name.
So i can't inherit from BaseEntity abstract class because it implies that the primary Key table must call "Id".

My question is :

Is it a problem to create a new Domain entity class who is not inherit from BaseEntity ? Like :

```
public class Signature
{
public int SignatureId { get; set; }

public string Hash{ get; set; }

  public.....
}
```

Maybe it must implies so problem during entity manipulations ? Can you advice me about that ?

Comment: do it simple, instead of SignatureId use Id ...what's a deal in it, you just need to store Ids.....on front end disply show signatureId instead of Id ....

Comment: Yes , it would be the best solution , but it will be impossible because the Table Signature is already used in several applications , there are some stored procedures who retrieved datas with SeignatureId Column select...

Comment: then only one thing can do need to manupulate it

Comment: @user1018697 check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be using both id and signatureId. So you will be inline with your client and nopcommerce.

Repository pattern is used in nopcommerce to store data using base entity. So creating an entity without inheriting from base would break the design.

Answer (score 0):

I am late but the answer is yes you can, even if you inherit from it. You just need to ignore it in the mapping like below;

```
public class Signature : BaseEntity
{
  public int SignatureId { get; set; }
  public string Hash{ get; set; }
  public.....
}
```

In the mapping i.e **Nop.Data -> Mapping**

```
public class SignatureMap : NopEntityTypeConfiguration<Signature>
{
    this.Ignore(c => c.Id);
    this.HasKey(c => c.SignatureId);
}
```

Comment: You can ignore Id, but repository pattern uses queries, which relies on Id. So queries  will break and wont return data.

Comment: @Jeyara it will ignor it for this entity only. And nopCommerce `EfRepository` doesn't rely on a coloumn called `Id` it relies on the type. Above entity `Signature` is already inherited from `BaseEntity`. So where can it make trouble ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, there was a query getbyid in efrepo.

Comment: `return this.Entities.Find(id);` this is entity framework job to check for appropriate primary key and we already specified that our primary key is different. It doesn't explicitly checking for column called `Id`.

Comment: check this article. it talks about primary key not a column called `Id` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx